# Qt UDP multicast Sockets still receiving even if wire disconnected

Tags: multithreading, qt, sockets, udp

The purpose of my little Qt application is to test an external ethernet switch.

I have 2 USB ethernet port installed on my PC.

I developed an application that setup an UDP socket that is bind to the interface related to the IP address that I set.

If **I open my application twice and set on each application the correct NIC**, after unplugging the wire between the NIC and the ethernet switch the communication between sockets stops.

But if I start **both sockets on different NICs into the same application** the communication still alive even after cable unplugged.
I think there is some kind IPC on the background when the sockets "live" in the same instance of an application.

Is there any option to disable the described behavior not involving multi-threading?